# How to prevent damp on a wall with no soffit(roof overhang)

Tags: waterproofing, brick, roofing, damp

One wall of my 1890's victorian house has no soffit (roof overhang). This wall also suffers from damp coming through the solid brick walls and I don't get that on any other exterior wall. The bricks are certainly not in perfect condition but there's no more visible damage there than on walls which are more exposed to driving rain.

I'm considering getting wider gutters installed to try and catch more rain during heavy showers. Are there other solutions I could consider?